# Is there any algorithm that can predict multi-variables(response variables) based on one independent variable

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, predictive-models

let me ask the question in detail with an example --

I have a historical dataset with columns(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

Now i have to predict (b,c,d,e,f,g) based on the value of 'a' and all the variables are inter-dependent on each other!

I did use K-NN, K-Means, regression model algorithms where i am able to predict one response variable. but in my case i need to predict multi-variables!

Can this done? Just need a right direction how to do that?

Comment: Consider, you have a dataset which says the revenue of bike rental store on a day based on number of rentals, cost per hour for rent.

Now my goal is to predict the number of rentals per month and cost per hour to reach my revenue goal of $50k?

Comment: Would you be able to build 6 models (one where a predicts b, one where a predicts c, ...) and combine the results?

Comment: In my case i am building the models separately and just combining the data into one data frame using R... this modeling gave me a decent accuracy!